# Having a swap partition == can't go to the BIOS menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, swap

It didn't happen before. Every time I create a swap partition, I can't go to BIOS settings (I can still boot and run windows or ubuntu, but I can't change BIOS settings), I get the password window and after that the screen gets all black (it does not turn off) and it keeps like that until I shut down the computer (after 10 min or so). If I delete the swap partition, the BIOS menu settings does load after 5-6 seconds.

I have tried using: the ubuntu installation gui, commandline (`mkswap`, `swapon` and changing /etc/fstab after that) and using gparted (modifying /etc/fstab after using it to get the swap UUID correct)

Any suggestions?

---

More info:

fdisk -l /dev/sda1 (where the swap partition is located):

Disk /dev/sda: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors

Disk Model: HGST HTS721010A9

Units: Sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk label type: gpt

Disk identifier: 41CD340B-CE19-4B0B-BA72-B74CEB4BC6A6

---

Device.  Start   End    Sectors   Size  Type

/dev/sda1      2048 7923711  7921664   3,8G Linux swap

---

(I if erase /dev/sda1, it works again)

Comment: Can you add to your question the result of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX`  when BIOS works and when it doesn't? (change /dev/sdX with your actual device)

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: That is a strange one! Have you tried using a swap file instead of a swap partition?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The things that I don't know exactly about a swap partition / Don't know if a swap partition is good in my case: is the swap file located on the same partition as the OS? (the OS is in the nvme, and I've heard that I sholdn't use an SSD for that, as It has a wear limit in writes) and can the swap file be shared between OS? (I use more than one linux OS on the same computer)

Comment: All the guides about how to create a swap file place it at /swapfile. So that’s at the root of the root partition. However because it’s a file I guess it can go anywhere so that might include a regular partition that you have mounted for some purpose. It would be a good question to ask on here! Do you monitor your swap usage? I have 8GB of ram and a 4GB swap. I’ve never seen swap in use so for me wear would not be an issue. Things may be different for you but by the time your drive is worn you would probably get a speed or size boost by replacing at lower cost than today.

Comment: The major disadvantage is the fact that I can't share the same swap space between OS. Also, I would like to know what is happening on the PC to not let me go to the BIOS (I'm studying a computer science related field, so I would like to understand this problem better).

Still, thanks for the idea. I think that is the perfect plan B. Also, after this I will learn more about swap files. Thank you.

Comment: I understand the desire to get to the bottom of this but there is more than a fair chance you won’t. I’d look for a work around. Try placing a small ext4 partition where the swap partition is and see if the same thing happens. If not try a swap partition elsewhere on sda. I’ve never see a problem like this before. One other point, on a 1000G drive you can have several  4G swap partitions and still have plenty of space if you don’t want to share them